# Detecting if a window is open jQuery PHP

Tags: php, jquery

Say I have a menu with the following

`<a href="/chat.php" class="newwindow">Chat</a>`

```
$(".newwindow a").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    window.open($(this).attr('href'),'Chat', 'width=500, height=576');
        return false;
});
```

So this jQuery along with HTML opens up a window for `chat.php`

Is there a way to detect across the rest of my website **if** this `chat.php` window is currently open and when it has closed too?

Reason being the chat is on every page of the website and when the use opens into a new window I would like to remove the chat from the active webpages

Comment: are the onload/onunload events unavailable to you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is how i check if the window was opened/blocked

```
var url = $(this).val();
var win  = window.open(url);
/* Detectar posible bloqueo de popups */
if (win == null || typeof(win) == "undefined" || (win == null && win.outerWidth == 0) || (win != null && win.outerHeight == 0) || win.test == "undefined"){
                    window.location.href = url;
}else if (win){
    win.onload = function(){
    if (win.screenX === 0) {
            win.close();
    }
   };
}
```